# ASP.net 4.5 Websocket encryption using ssl

Tags: asp.net, websocket

i want to know will it be enough to install ssl certificate on server and then call
the websocket with "wss://" currently its working with "ws://". I am going to buy and configure ssl on my server will it work???
i am learning websocket following this article http://alexjmackey.wordpress.com/2012/05/01/websockets-with-asp-net-4-5-and-visual-studio-11/

??

Comment: Could you please share some details, steps, how did you do it? I have a websocket asp.net server which uses Microsoft.WebSockets, it works fine over ws://.... Now I would like to switch to wss, and completely remove ws support.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, it should work. The default port for wss is also 443. Remember to use the domain name rather than the IP address to connect.
 If the certificate is signed by a valid CA, it should be fine, otherwise ensure you use it also for the web site, so the user can accept the browser warning.